# Get JSON data as input stream in apache flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I want to get input stream as JSON array from an url. How do i setup source so that the input is obtained continuously in apache flink using datastream.In short i want to get json data continuously from an url without getting the flink job shut down.

Answer (score 0):

You can continuously get a stream of JSON stringified objects using a `socketTextStream` source.

Flink socket example: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/socket/SocketWindowWordCount.java

More on data sources: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you explain a bit more that how to use the above source to fetch data from an url and not a socket.

Comment: @Kspace the socket requires a host and port params. So pass a URL as the host. e.g. `http://myhost.com/` ...

Comment: @Kspace if you consider I answered your question, please accept and upvote the answer.